# SQL Server 2008 Backup Compression Standard Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, compression, backup

I'm trying to backup a database in SQL Server 2008 and have the database compressed using the new compression feature. However, when I run the following code, I get a weird error message:

```
Backup Database <Database> To Disk 'C:\Backup' With Compression
```

I get this error message:

> Backup Database With Compression is not supported on Standard Edition

Does this mean I have to upgrade to the full version or is there a way to enable compression in standard edition?

Comment: You will have to run a script to zip or rar the file after the backup, just like the old days

Comment: Yes it's one of the many times you wish the command line in windows was as good and easy as in Linux...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Backup Compression is not supported on SQL 2008 Express, Workgroup, or Standard editions, only on Enterprise.  There is no way to turn this on without upgrading your version to Enterprise.

Although you can't backup with compression on those versions, you can RESTORE from compressed backups.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 18):

I realize this is an old post, but just to throw this out there since it showed as one of the first few entries on a Google search - with SQL Server 2008 R2, Standard Edition also gets backup compression.  More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719.aspx

Comment: only restoring compressed backups or I missed something ? edit: ok I understand, in 2012 edition they are back to the "from Enterprise" thing...

Answer (score 3):

Might be helpful as well - to determine which edition of SQL Server you're running on, run the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')
```

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

Answer (score 1):

You need Enterprise Edition for that

Answer (score -1):

`BACKUP DATABASE WITH COMPRESSION` is not supported on Express Edition (64-bit).

Comment: Question was clearly referring to "Standard Edition" not Express Edition

Answer (score -1):

To confirm, from SQL Server 2012 onwards, all editions (except Express and Web) support backup compression: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Nope. SQL Server 2012 doesn't support compressed backups in Web Edition (for example).

Comment: Many thanks for the comment and the helpful downvote. I have re-checked the documentation and corrected the answer.