# T-sql for checking SQL Server EDITION can compress backup

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

How can you check, **through t-sql**, if your SQL-server **edition** (not version) supports compressing backups through

```
WITH COMPRESSION
```

?

Also, if only possible to do this through checking your edition somehow (like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658724/1655580), how re-usable is such an approach if developing against SQL Server 2008 R2 and then comparing with later versions?

What I'm primarily interested in is if there is a 'direct' way to get to know this, and not indirectly via checking the edition.

Thanks

PS:

This

```
USE my_database;
GO
SELECT value 
FROM sys.configurations 
WHERE name = 'backup compression default' ;
```

is not what I'm looking for, but is the only thing I get when I searched myself.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2013/03/does-my-sql-server-database-support.html

Comment: I get nothing from
SELECT feature_name,feature_id
FROM
sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;

Comment: What does this mean - "The DMV will return no rows if no features restricted to a particular edition are used by the database."? I'm using compression in my t-sql!

Comment: Let's say you know that in the future, `Feature X` will be available in SQL Server 2033.  How would you expect to check for the existence of that feature (via tsql) in SQL 2014 or earlier?

Comment: I would guess that compression is a feature that will prevail for some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this query is great (from [H2](http://blog.h2consultants.com/2012/sql-query-to-determine-if-sql-server-supports-backup-compression))

> SELECT ISNULL((SELECT value FROM sys.configurations WHERE name = 'backup compression default'),-1)

"The above query will return 0 or 1 if the SQL server supports backup compression and -1 if it does not."

Comment: Setting this as the accepted answer since it seems a better solution than producing the error, plus number of votes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use it and see whether it produces an error:

```
exec(N'set noexec on; backup database master
to disk=''c:\backup''
WITH COMPRESSION')
print @@ERROR
```

If it's valid, `@@ERROR` will be `0`. If it's invalid, it will be `155`. Of course, the `NOEXEC` means it doesn't actually attempt to run the backup operation. You can use a similar technique to discover the availability or not of any features that will produce parse time errors.

Comment: okay, that is a solution of course. If nothing else comes up I might just have to do that.

Comment: This didn't work for me. :( It always prints 0 on SQL Server 2008 Express SP3 (10.0.5500.0).